# Kodaira dimensions

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am learning about schemes, specifically abstrac varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ and I want to read a good book or reference where explain the kodaira dimensions, somebody can help me?

Comment: I've never looked at it, but the reference I always see mentioned is Ueno's _Classification theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex spaces_. His introductory books seemed very friendly, so hopefully the same is true of this; unfortunately it was written in 1975 and hence is probably not state of the art.

Comment: @Hoot thanks, I´ll go to see the reference.

Comment: Also, Mori talks about some of this in his article for the 1985 Bowdoin conference. Definitely worth a look but almost certainly at a higher level.